# Django if condition

Tags: django

I want to do it with django in template if condition

```
{% if object.count <= item.min_count %}
    <tr class="bg-warning">
{% else %}
    <tr>
{% endif %}
```

this works well, but if i do the below attemp, django fails raising no errors

```
{% if object.count <= item.min_count %}
    <tr class="bg-warning">
{% if object.count <= (item.min_count/2) %}.   # how can i do it?
    <tr class="bg-danger">
{% else %}
    <tr>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates should be kept without calculations as it is something that should happen in views

If you still want to do it, you could create your own [template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-custom-filters) for division or use [django-mathfilters](https://pypi.org/project/django-mathfilters/)

with mathfilters installed

```
{% if object.count <= item.min_count|div:2 %}
    <tr class="bg-danger">
```